# VirtualBox проблема импорта

Tags: virtualbox, виртуальная-машина, импорт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Пробую импортировать, но выдает ошибку, на той компьютере от которого экспортирую работает

Comment: Место свободное на диске в наличии?